# Texturing for games using Blender is confusing

Tags: texturing, uv, unity, unreal-engine, toon-shading

I am a total noob who is interested in understanding how textures for video gaming engines work and I am completely lost. I can't find tutorials or clear explanations of these topics so I would love to have some insight from some industry professionals. I found a tutorial of a really cool looking mushroom, which I believe is made by a style called toon shading, which reminds me of games like Borderlands and Zelda. Now in the tutorial, this entire process is made inside of blender and as far as I understand, without this technique called UV mapping or Unvrapping, you cannot transfer them to game engines. (I still don't understand the complete difference between these terms as well). Now I kind of have an understanding of what UVs are, they are essentially transferring the surface of the 3D object to a 2D plane, so artists can paint them easily and have these maps get recognized by the game engines(I guess?) like Unity or UE. However, what I don't understand is why the node-based system of Blender cannot be transferred to game engines. after you UV unwrap your object, how can you transfer all of this data, the colors, the grease pencil lines(the black lines) into a 2D map without ruining your texture? Is this why every single full pipeline tutorial I see uses the software called Substance 3D Painter?
[image]
I haven't been able to find a simple in-depth tutorial on how substance painter works with stylized art. I know the concept of hand- painting but from most of the sped-up tutorials, I have seen people are able to create stuff like this paper without painting anything, they just click on the different parts of the object, apply the materials from the software, and get this stylized look without painting anything. After doing some research I believe some of these smart materials(I may be pulling terms from my bottom at this point, sorry I am really having a hard time understanding all of this!) are provided by substance painter, some are created by professionals and sold for usage and some are coming from a completely different software, where you create these textures. I believe it is called substance designer and the stuff some people achieve with that program is unbelievable.

[image]

like this lava rock thingy, I know the artist created this using Substance 3D, but I don't understand where this is used, do you make a complete volcano zone-game map thingy with this material without ever painting anything, do you apply this material directly on the game engine or do you transfer this to blender and somehow export it as a completely textured model to your game?

[image]

Now to wrap this mess of a post up, a final image of this incredibly cool level that is created in Unreal engine. I reached out to the artist who created this but sadly could not get an answer. The listed programs he used do not include Substance 3D Painter. So does this mean that he created these awesome looking textures in substance designer, and applied these textures to his 3D models directly in Unreal Engine? If so does this mean that Blender is only used for modeling and sculpting? If someone desires to create awesome looking stylized textures, without hand painting or adobe products and transfer those textures to game engines, what they should do? Does blender provide the necessary tools tocreate stuff like the pictures? Thanks in advance.

[image]

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/g2WDRm(The original link for the final picture)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.